# Метод Dispose()

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть пользовательский контрол CustomProgressBar для отображения текста помимо анимации прогресса. Брал куски с разных вариантов, но вдруг в последний момент заметил, что во многих пользовательских ProgressBar присутствует метод Dispose().Пропесочил кучу статей, но до меня так и не дошло, нужен ли этот метод в моем контроле, и если да, то как реализовать.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public String CustomText { get; set; }

    public CustomProgressBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(g, rect);
        rect.Inflate(-3, -3);
        if (Value > 0)
        {
            Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, (int)(((float)Value / (float)Maximum) * (float)rect.Width), rect.Height);
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(g, clip);
        }

        using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10))
        {
            SizeF len = g.MeasureString(CustomText, f);
           
            Point location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((Width / 2) - len.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32((Height / 2) - len.Height / 2));
            
            g.DrawString(CustomText, f, Brushes.Black, location);
        }
    }

    //Для устранения мерцания контрола применяем двойную буферизацию на уровне формы, а не на уровне контрола
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myParams = base.CreateParams;

            // Установка флага для двойной буферизации WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            myParams.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;

            return myParams;
        }
    }
}
}
```

P.S. Есть еще вопрос по этому коду. Переопределенный метод protected override CreateParams CreateParams. Там, откуда я его взял, он был прописан в определении пользовательского контрола.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1082902/How-to-Paint-on-Top-of-a-ProgressBar-using-Csharp   (2016 год)
Пишут что в отличие от свойства DoubleBuffered, этот метод устраняет мерцание для всей формы и контролов на ней, но вот вставляют ее кто куда, то в код основной формы, то в код пользовательского контрола (как здесь)... Так где же все-таки  правильно переопределять CreateParams?Будет ли она так же работать, если переопределить в кастомном  контроле?

Comment: Ваш класс не владеет никакими собственными ресурсами, которые нуждались бы в освобождении. Поэтому переопределять Dispose не нужно.

Comment: По поводу CreateParams - никто не ответит здесь. Задавайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как сказано в документе [Implement Dispose Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), этот метод нужен чтобы:

- Освобождать неуправляемые ресурсы
- Пробрасывать вызов Dispose в IDisposable объекты, которые вы создавали

Поэтому смотрим ваш код, и ищем не захватывали ли вы неуправляемые ресурсы и не создавали ли IDisposable объекты.

Единственное что бросается в глаза, это создание объекта Font в методе OnPaint. Но здесь вы его обернули в `using`, который разворачивается компилятором в try/finally с вызовом Dispose. Поэтому получается что реализовывать метод Dispose вам не нужно.

Кстати, метод Dispose уже реализован в базовом классе Control. Поэтому если бы вам было нужно его реализовать в вашем контроле, достаточно было бы переопределить уже существующий метод:

```cs
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    // ваш код
}
```

Что касается объекта Font, его можно хранить в свойтве вашего компонента, чтобы сэкономить ресурсы при отрисовке. Вот тогда и понадобится переопределить метод Dispose.

Comment: Объект Font задействует неуправляемые ресурсы? Я раньше думал что в среде NET неуправляемыми ресурсами считаются вызовы WIN32 API, а все остальное вроде как контролируется средой. И теперь вот потерялся немного с пониманием.

Comment: @Дмитрий, насколько я помню, объект Font захватывает GDI объект.

Comment: В целом я премного благодарен за развернутый ответ и рад что для моего контрола всего хватает))), а в частности побег я учить мат. часть)), пока в голове не все до конца складывается...